# Format words in android EditText view on textchange

Tags: android, formatting, textchanged

I am working with android 2.2.
I want to format multiple words as per my adapter contains.
like

```
final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        adapter.add("aaaa");
        adapter.add("abaa");
        adapter.add("acaa");
        adapter.add("adaa");
        adapter.add("aaba");
        adapter.add("aaca");
        adapter.add("aaba");
        adapter.add("aaae");
```

I have one EditText-view in which i am I writing text but if on text change i found any word which is matching with adapters value that i want to highlight.

Please refer the following code on text change but not getting perfect output.

```
@Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                CharSequence cs;
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                str = myAutoComplete.getText().toString();
            for(int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++)
            {   
                String s2 = adapter.getItem(i).toString().toLowerCase();    

                if (str.contains(s2) == true) 
                {   Log.e("s2",s2);                     
                    str =  str.replaceAll(s2, "<font color='red'>"+s2+"</font>");
                    Log.e("str",str);
                    myAutoComplete.setText(Html.fromHtml(str), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
                }

            }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
        SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder(eT
                    .getText().toString());

            ForegroundColorSpan fcs = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GREEN);

                   // 5,10 specifies selected characters
            ssb.setSpan(fcs, 5, 10, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

            eT.setText(ssb);
```

Comment: by this way i will set whole edittext text format but i want want to edit only words

Comment: Do you have any other words apart from search words??